# Значения регрессии занижены относительно данных

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Я строю модель линейной регрессии. Построив график предсказанных результатов я заметил, что значения регрессии лежат практически целиком ниже истинных. Т.е. прибавив константу к значениям модели я фактически "улучшу" результат. Какие могут быть причины?

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, interaction_only = True).fit(X_train_scaled)
X_train_poly = poly.transform(X_train_scaled)
X_test_poly = poly.transform(X_test_scaled)

rdg = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0.01)
rdg.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

y_test_predict = rdg.predict(X_test_scaled)
y_train_predict = rdg.predict(X_train_scaled)

print('R^2 training: %.3f, R^2 test: %.3f' % (
      (metrics.r2_score(y_train, y_train_predict)), 
      (metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_test_predict))))

rdg_metrics = get_regression_metrics('Ridge Regression', y_test, y_test_predict)
rdg_metrics
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно хотя бы кусок данных посмотреть. Непонятно также, что именно вы рисуете на графике. Метрики должны печататься - вы их тоже не показали. Разбиение данных на трейн и тест - тоже не показано. Зато показано, как вы делаете полиномиальные фичи... которые в дальнейшем не используете. Надо в вопросе показывать только релевантный вопросу код.

Comment: И вообще - что за данные? Может вы временные ряды предсказываете, тогда это вообще другая история, там легко может быть такое, если вы предсказываете текущую цену по ценам на несколько дней назад. При наличии тренда то вниз, то вверх, предсказание будет усреднять данные. Если на тесте тренд повышательный, как на графике, предсказание будет опаздывать за трендом и занижать прогноз.